# raspberry pi 4B speaker interval time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-os

I want to make a raspberry pi 4B speaker using python. And I would like to use a loop to open the `voice.mp3` file where different values are created over and over again. I tried to use the `playsound` module, but for some reason which I don't know the raspberry pi cannot speak. And when using commands such as `mpg321`, if you do not give time.sleep, the words are overlapped and cannot be understood. So the question is, is there a way to solve this or make the Raspberry Pi give the appropriate time.sleep according to the string? Or is there something wrong with the code below? Additionally, the python version is 3.7.6.

tried `playsound` module python

```
#-*-coding: utf-8-*-
import os, playsound
playsound.playsound('./voice.mp3')
```

tried `mpg321` command python

```
import os
os.system('mpg321 voice.mp3 &')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the last character from the command

```
mpg321 voice.mp3 &
```

That `&` means "run a command but don't wait for it to finish". If you don't want the words to overlap, you'd better wait.